# PowerBI: Bind Before/After date in slicer to two Direct Query Parameters

Tags: powerbi

I have a PowerBI report that with a Date/Time slicer so user can select different time ranges.

[image]

After the user selects a window, I would like to run a Direct Query using the selected Before/After times as two separate input parameters.

The problem I am running into is that the slicer is derived from one field so I can't simply bind the same field to two different parameters because it will have no concept of min/max date.

[image]

I have tried creating two separate measures which select the min and max timestamp respectively, but PowerBI does not provide an option to bind the measure to the `StartDate`, `EndDate` parameters the same way it does for the `timestamp` field.

How can I derive the min/max timestamps from a Date/Time field and bind them to two separate parameters that I can use in a Direct Query?